# Broadcasting in L2 Switch

Tags: switch, switching, broadcast, switchport, switching-modes

**Hey guys, This is a Noob question.**

When a broadcast frame is received on a switch from a specific port, will it be automatically destined to all the ports in a switch ?

---------- (or) ----------

Will it be forwarded by the ports in a switch between each other ? i.e. when one port receives broadcast, it will forward to the next port when the frame doesn't match with itself.

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you can provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 2):

A broadcast frame is forwarded to all switch ports but the one it was received from. When several switches are connected to each other the broadcast will eventually reach all ports in this broadcast domain.

That is unless you've got VLANs set up. VLANs separate the network into distinct broadcast domains that do not communicate with each other on layer 2 (very often your Ethernet network). You can communicate across VLANs through routers on layer 3.